# I can't call setup() for some reason

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I can't call setup() on my p5js project or change any of the boolean values to false after the thing is started.

I've tried making a new function called `reset()` and instead of calling `setup()` I called `reset()` but it didn't work.

```
let x, y;
let start;
let trianglespeed;
let x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3;
let r;
let lost, playing, win;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  r = random(900, 4000);
  x = 100 - 20;
  y = 200 - 20;
  x1 = r
  y1 = 150;
  x2 = x1 + 10;
  y2 = 180;
  x3 = x2 + 10;
  y3 = 150;
  textSize(30);
  noStroke();
  start = "Click screen to play";
  trianglespeed = 0;
  lost = false;
  playing = false;
  win = false;
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  fill(112, 166, 255);
  text(start, 70, 100);
  fill(178, 178, 178);
  rect(x, y, 20, 20);
  fill(255, 99, 99);
  triangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
  console.log(mouseX);
  x1 = x1 + trianglespeed;
  x2 = x2 + trianglespeed;
  x3 = x3 + trianglespeed;
  if (playing == true) {
    if (x1 <= 70) {
      trianglespeed = 0;
      start = "Press R to restart";
      x1 = x1;
      x2 = x1 + 10;
      x3 = x1 + 20;
      lost = true;
    }
  }
  console.log(playing, lost, win);
}

function mousePressed() {
  if (lost == false) {
    start = "";
    trianglespeed = -10;
    playing = true;
  }
  if (playing == true) {
    if (x2 >= 80 && x2 <= 100) {
      start = "you win, press R to restart";
      trianglespeed = 0;
      x1 = x1;
      x2 = x1 + 10;
      x3 = x1 + 20;
      win = true;
    }
  }
}

function KeyPressed() {
  if (keyCode == R) {
    setup();

//the problem ^^^
  }
}
```

I expect that after I press R the whole thing would restart but it didn't.

Tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: this is because `setup()` is entry point, so it execute in the start of code, so you cant use  setup(); you need other function to handle whatever you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok the problem was this

```
function KeyPressed() {
  if (key == "r") {
    reset();

  }
}
```

the K on the keypressed function was a capital K not a normal one.

Comment: jajajaj really?? im glad you found the solution

Answer (score 1):

p5.js says:

> The setup() function is called once when the program starts. It's used
>   to define initial environment properties such as screen size and
>   background color and to load media such as images and fonts as the
>   program starts. There can only be one setup() function for each
>   program and it shouldn't be called again after its initial execution.

and has a note

> Note: Variables declared within setup() are not accessible within
>   other functions, including draw().

this means you can't use the `setup` function to reset values because it is for initialization of the code.

You can look at the official page: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/setup

If you want to change some values you can use another function to handle your code.

Comment: Soo what should i use to restart/reload the whole thing?

Comment: @Subscribetopewdiepie you can put all logic of initials variables on a function, and call it in `setup()`, and when you need init all vars again, call the same function in the `draw()` or anywhere

Comment: ok so i changed the keypressed, instead of calling setup() i called reset(). In the reset() its basically almost the same stuff as setup() like turning vars to default and all the other things, but its still not working like i said in the post. Idk if its the keypressed function that has the problem or the way i put it up.

Comment: @Subscribetopewdiepie check keypressed() function: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyPressed

Comment: @Subscribetopewdiepie or this https://p5js.org/examples/input-keyboard.html